# What does the .run syntaxis / statement mean

Tags: apex, trigger

I have bumped in some code like below:

```
new InvTriggerHandler().run('InvTrigger');
```

What does the .run('InvTrigger') mean? I have googled but could not find a proper answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given syntax means that there is a method `run` in the instance of class `InvTriggerHandler` (or it's ancestor) which takes 1 parameter with type String.

The entire line means following:

```
new InvTriggerHandler().run('InvTrigger');
```

1. Create instance of class InvTriggerHandler: `new InvTriggerHandler()`.
2. Call method `run` with parameter `'InvTrigger'` of that newly created instance.